# SQL Update on Azure ML Not Working?

Tags: sql, azure, machine-learning, data-scrubbing

I'm trying to clean some data in Azure ML.  I have an Apply SQL Transform block with the following code in it:

```
UPDATE t1
SET CreditScore = -1 
WHERE CreditScore>900;
```

It is a numeric column.  When I visualize the output, there are 0 rows and 0 columns.  Going into the block there are 225k rows.
Anybody have a clue what is going on?

Comment: The data is being imported from a CSV file.  There are no triggers.  It just goes from the import CSV block to a couple of Edit Metadata blocks, which rename some columns, and then to the SQL Transform block

Comment: Is `CreditScore` stored as text or a numeric type?

Comment: CreditScore is numeric

Comment: What data type specifically?

Comment: Max is about 40000 and min is about 300. It looks like all are integer, but Azure ML just lists it as "Numeric"

Answer (score 1):

"You cannot execute a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement on a view. However, you can create a trigger that fires on an attempt to DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE on a view and perform other operations in the body of the trigger."
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn905914.aspx

I found an other solution. Go over SELECT DISTINCT - create a new table and make an innter join. Works fine for me :-)